# How to use .htaccess in a non open-basedir path of Synology/DSM 6.1

Tags: .htaccess, synology, php-cgi, dsm

I am trying to use the trick described by Rob Van Aarle [here](http://www.robvanaarle.com/blog/2014/08/embedded-php-app-without-dependencies-for-synology-nas/) to execute php pages in "paths not allowed" by default for Synology's web server...

The purpose is to create packages which do not depend on "[Init_3rdparty](https://www.cphub.net/?p=init3p)" (this famous package which allows users to run php pages in path like /volumeX/@appstore/ on their Synology)

Basically, Rob suggests to call a script which execute the php page using php-cgi (/usr/local/bin/php56-cgi)

Ex.: call to a cgi like this to execute the page test.php located next to it.

```
#!/bin/sh
REDIRECT_STATUS=1 export REDIRECT_STATUS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$(pwd)/test.php export SCRIPT_FILENAME
/usr/bin/php-cgi -d open_basedir=none $SCRIPT_FILENAME 2>&1
```

This is working fine.

But the complete idea of Rob is to use a .htaccess to redirect calls to any php pages toward a generic cgi script.

.htaccess

```
# Turn on rewrite engine.
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite existing php files to the router script.
# Apache on the Synology NAS automatically redirects url
# containing '../' to the corresponding real path, before
# the router script is executed, so it's impossible to
# execute system files.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ router.cgi [PT,L,QSA,NE]
```

router.cgi

```
#!/bin/sh

# Set redirect_status to 1 to get php cgi working.
REDIRECT_STATUS=1 export REDIRECT_STATUS

# Fix several $_SERVER globals.
PHP_SELF=$SCRIPT_URL export PHP_SELF
SCRIPT_NAME=$SCRIPT_URL export SCRIPT_NAME

# Strip web base from SCRIPT_URL, concat it to parent directory
# and apply realpath to construct absolute path to requested script.
WEB_BASE="/webman/3rdparty"
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$(pwd)/..${SCRIPT_URL:${#WEB_BASE}}
SCRIPT_FILENAME=`realpath $SCRIPT_FILENAME`
export SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Execute the requested PHP file.
/usr/local/bin/php56-cgi -d open_basedir=none $SCRIPT_FILENAME 2>&1
```

I have added traces in the cgi and the problem is that it's never called on my DSM 6.1. So, it seems to me that the .htaccess is not "enabled". Concretely, a call to the php page is downloading that file.

Is an .htaccess assumed to be used on Synology DSM 6.1, when the DSM accesses a php page located in a non allowed path? If it should work, what could be misconfigured on the NAS ?

MANY thx in adv. for sharing your experience on this!

[Here is the demo package](https://github.com/robvanaarle/syno-helloworld-php) created by Rob to illustrate his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out the problem. The latest versions of DSM are using nginx by default instead of apache, as a web server. And nginx is [not using htaccess files](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/).